# Concrete5 background image not showing

Tags: php, concrete5

I'm working on a page type in Concrete5 that has a full-width section that uses an image for the background. [Here](http://staging.lifestylerevolutionstx.com/combat-ready.html) is what the page is supposed to look like, and [here](http://staging.lifestylerevolutionstx.com/) it is in C5. I used the technique described in [this C5 forum thread](http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/themes/customising-theme-background-images/) without any luck. I'm thinking the issue probably has to do with the reference to the image file. I do not understand how the attribute gets associated with the actual image file. Here is the code included in my :

```
?php
    $bg_img = $c->getAttribute('gymMatBackgroundImage');
    $bg_img_src = $bg_img->getRelativePath();
?>
<style type="text/css">
    .bar4 {
        background-image: url(<?php echo $bg_img_src; ?>);
    }
</style>
```

and here is the section that needs the background image:

```
<div class="fullWidthBar bar4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <h3>Sign Up</h3>
            <div style="width: 50%; height:300px; background-color:white; float:right;">Calendar Placeholder</div>
            <p>Sign on for a three or six month commitment to recieve a discount</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I looked at the source of the page you linked to can't see where any of that code is getting output. I don't even see "Sign Up" in the code. The first step to debugging is to look at the source and see what `<?php echo $bg_img_src; ?>` is outputting. That'll give us an idea of what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use that code with an image file on your server -- instead you upload an image to the file manager and choose it from there. See http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/themes/customising-theme-background-images/#190906

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a how-to on setting up background image on a page a few months ago. It explains with screenshots how you create the attribute and how you use the attribute on a page. Have a look here: http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/designers/use-attributes-to-set-background-images/

Edit: Just noticed my reply was a bit late, but the information is still valid.

Comment: You should consider adding the relevant information or at least a relevant snippet of information to this answer in case the link becomes broken in the future.